# Pass RDD in scala function. Output Dataframe

Tags: scala, function, dataframe, apache-spark, rdd

say I have the below csv and many more like it.

```
val csv = sc.parallelize(Array(
  "col1, col2, col3",
  "1, cat, dog",
  "2, bird, bee"))
```

I would like to apply the below functions to the RDD to convert it to a data frame with the desired logic below. I keep running into the error `error: not found: value DataFrame`

How can I correct this?

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

/
```

In most cases I would  read CSV files directly as a dateframe using Spark's core functionality, but I am unable to in this case.

Any/all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in order not to get `error: not found: value DataFrame` you must add the following import:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
```

and your method declaration should be like this:

```scala
def udf(fName : RDD[String]): DataFrame = { ...
```

Comment: Thank you. This is odd. even when I correct the the import and method declaration it throws me an error.

```
command-3676982235166079:13: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Unit
 required: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
    (which expands to)  org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]
  )  }
```

Comment: @CookieMonster you are not returning anything. Either add an extra line with just `result` or just remove the `val result =` and just leave the statement.